# making stacked responsive blocks that change height and width on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I would like to create 3 block layout that looks like this:

```
_________
|   |   |
|   |___|
|   |   |
---------
```

width is % based. So is padding-bottom, to make box responsive both height and width.

css looks like this:

```
#block-home header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
#block-home footer {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
#block-home aside {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 23%;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

My problem is that bottom border of 1 and 3rd blocks are never aligned. By changing width of browser, they get misaligned.

What is a possible solution here?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B93tx/2/)

Comment: If you are dealing with CSS and HTML only then why a jQuery tag is there?

Comment: @effone jquery often provides acceptable solution to complicated layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `padding-bottom` is calculated according to the width of the element so. You will need to use the `height` property.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) :

> Percentages refer to the width of the containing block

To achieve your layout, you can use `position:absolute;` either on the right blocks or on the left one so they/it adapt to the height of the other block.

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B93tx/31/)** with the 2 right blocks set to `position: absolute;`

CSS code :

```
#block-home{
    position:relative;
}

#block-home header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}
#block-home footer {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:60%;
    height:70%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
}
#block-home aside {
    position: absolute;
    top:70%;
    left:60%;
    height:30%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I used padding-bottom precisely for this property. I don't think this kind of layout is even possible with heights. But I might be wrong, can you give me an example of working layout? thanks!